# How do I see all the methods/members of a COM Object?

Tags: powershell, com, qtp

I'm trying to get QuickTest.Application and QuickTest.RunResultsOptions COM objects, but when I access them this way, I don't get all the members that are listed in the official Help files.

```
PS> $app = New-Object -ComObject QuickTest.Application -Strict
PS> $app | Get-Member
```

For example, I know that `Launch()` exists and can use it from a vbscript.

```
Dim app
Set app = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")

app.Launch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, PowerShell won't cast COM objects to their interfaces, which makes a bunch of methods invisible on some of the COM APIs I use.  I actually have a COMObjects.Types.ps1xml file which I import in my profile:

```
Update-TypeData   -PrependPath "(Split-Path $Profile)\COMObject.Types.ps1xml"
```

The actual types.ps1xml file is [on PoshCode](http://poshcode.org/1998), and it adds GetProperty/SetProperty/InvokeMethod members to COM objects for exactly this reason: accessing members that aren't visible to Powershell

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try it.

Comment: Can you give me example of usage of method 'InvokeMethod' with params?

Comment: i guess i found the way by myself

Comment: :) Sorry to leave you hanging, was on vacation ;)

Comment: This isn't working for me. I setup the types file, made the update call, but my instance of `QuickTest.Application` doesn't have important methods, like `Launch`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because Get-Member doesn't show them doesn't mean they are not there when it comes to COM objects.  You will have to find some documentation to see what the member name is and what parameters it takes.  This isn't a problem with .NET objects because it always has metadata availabe to describe types and type member signatures.  PowerShell doesn't always have this info for COM objects.